# Get circles x and y center

Tags: python, dxf, ezdxf

My target is to get all circles from `dxf` file with 3 information like: `circumference, X center, Y center`. So far i am able to get circumference. How can i get `Y & X`? This is my current code:

```
import sys
import ezdxf

doc = ezdxf.readfile("File.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()

for e in msp:    
    if e.dxftype() == 'CIRCLE':
            dc = 2 * math.pi * e.dxf.radius
            print('circumference: ' + str(dc))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The center of the circle is `e.dxf.center` as `Vec3` object in the Object Coordinate System (OCS). The OCS is the WCS if the extrusion vector is (0, 0, 1), which is the case most of the time for 2D entities.

Sometimes mirrored 2D entities have an inverted extrusion vector (0, 0, -1) in this case, it is necessary to transform the OCS coordinates into WCS coordinates:

```
for e in msp.query("CIRCLE"):
    ocs = e.ocs()
    wcs_center = ocs.to_wcs(e.dxf.center)
    x = wcs_center.x
    y = wcs_center.y
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, it seem Circle has a 'center' attribute so

```
e.center
```

should give you the co-ordinates

https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfentities/circle.html